# Get a timezone GMT time?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've been storing user messages in my database using DATETIME columns. I need to display the message's sent time to users in different countries, since the database uses GMT+0 I need to adjust the retrieved time to the user's timezone.

The current user's timezone has been set with date_default_timezone_set() How do I get the it's GMT +- time?

EDIT

Following the idea of @doniyor this is what I did:

```
 // Get server hour
$localtime = localtime();
$serverHour = $localtime[2]; # The server's timezone is used by default before defining one

// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('user's timezone goes here');

// Get user hour
$localtime = localtime(); # Now localtime gives the user's time since timezone has been changed
$userHour = $localtime[2];
$timeAdjustment =  $userHour - $serverHour < -12 ? 24 + $userHour - $serverHour : $userHour - $serverHour; // Calculate hours to add to rows got from db to match user's time

// Example of a row adjusted to match user's time
    $adjustTime =  ($userHour - $serverHour < -12 ? 24 + $userHour - $serverHour : ($userHour - $serverHour > 12 ? $userHour - $serverHour - 24 : $userHour - $serverHour)*60*60; // strtotime is in seconds so $timeAdjustment needs *60*60 to convert to seconds too
```

I've tested this on PHP5+Apache but probably results vary depending on server configuration.

Comment: Try using unix timestamps and then convert them to dates

Comment: It's just the page is built using Datetime, so probably if I changed to timestamps I would get a lot of bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wrong, please dont downvote :)

If you get the timezone time in client browser and check the difference, if there is difference, then add or substract this difference-value depending on the location of the client.

Comment: You mean comparing the time in my server with the user's? That would work but I don't know how to get the time the database/server uses to compare it with the user's current time

Comment: There must be also something like  get_server_time() function, i am on the way, cannot google now :D

Comment: I browsed a bit but couldn't find such function, however I found out just getting the time before setting the user's timezone uses the server's default timezone effectively getting the server's time. So I'm just getting it before setting the timezone and again afterwards to get the user's time. I accepted the answer and copied the code.

Comment: Great! Glad to have been able to help someone who has more scored than me :D

Answer (score 2):

> The current user's timezone has been set with date_default_timezone_set() How do I get the it's GMT +- time?

You can't. Due to the vagaries of Daylight Saving Time, the offset is not constant -- it can change depending on the date.

Use [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) (together with a bit of string parsing) to convert a GMT date/time to a UNIX timestamp, then use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to display that in the current time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the values of the date values to JavaScript as a UNIX timestamp. For example, using AJAX:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'time' => strtotime($row['msg_time']),
    'msg' => 'hello world',
));
```

Then, use `Date()` to convert it into the user's local time:

```
var msgTime = new Date(data.time * 1000);
```